# how to run multiple sparql queries in java?

Tags: sparql, jena

I am new to sparql and jena api.my project is to select some ontology and extract meta data e.g. ontology classes,properties etc using jena and sparql.i dont know how to run multiple queries of sparql in one program?

Comment: Do you know how to run one query?

Comment: give some more details. have you successfully ran a query in sparql?

Answer (score 0):

The documentation is pretty good: http://jena.apache.org/documentation/query/manipulating_sparql_using_arq.html

Once you would be able to run a single query, it is straightforward to run multiple queries, even in a multi-thread environment.